# TensorFlow GPU on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, installation, gpu, ubuntu-20.04, cuda

The [Tensorflow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#install_cuda_with_apt) details how to install Tensorflow with GPU support for Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04. I can't find anything up to date for Ubuntu 20.04 however.

How do you install Tensorflow with GPU support on Ubuntu 20.4?

*Details: GPU NVIDIA GeForce GTX 850M*

Comment: Instruction should be the same as for Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Really? Instructions are different for Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04. How comes there is no difference between 18.04 and 20.04 ?